# Discord script to use Guilds.Join permission

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

So I have a website and when a user authorizes the auth2 link I get the user's secret and then I want them to join the support guild. I tried in different ways but it always says:
{"message": "401: Unauthorized", "code": 0} (I'm 100% sure that the auth2 code works. I also know that the bot that adds the user must be in the guild (also done))

```
async def join_server(user_token: str, guild_id: int):
headers = {
    'Authorization': f'Bot {user_token}'
}

try:
    response = requests.put(f'https://discord.com/api/v10/guilds/{guild_id}/members/@me', headers=headers) # I also tried to replace @me with userID but it doesn't work
    print(response.status_code)
    print(response.text)  # This will print the response content
    return response.status_code
except requests.exceptions.RequestException as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    return 500  # Return an error status code
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this doesn't work is because discord's API doesn't have a *Add Current Guild as Member* route, the only route discord has for adding members is the [*Add Guild Member*](https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member) route. This routes path as listed in the documentation is `/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}`. To successfully add a user to a guild you need the [*guilds.join*](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/oauth2#shared-resources) scope in your oauth2 link as well as the id of the guild and the user you want to add to said guild. You also need to change the way you send the put request to the aforementioned add guild member route. You can accomplish all of this with your modified method:

```py
def join_server(access_token: str, guild_id: Union[str, int], user_id: Union[str, int]) -> dict:
        """
        Attempts to add a user using their access token by sending a put request directly to
        `discord.com/api/guilds/{guild.id}/members/{user.id}` returns a request status code, if the return
        statement is 500, an error has occurred.
        """
        token = "Bot Token" # Bot Token Here

        headers = {
            "Authorization": f"Bot {token}",
            "Content-Type": "application/json"
        }

        json_data = json.dumps({
            "access_token": access_token
        })

        try:        
            response = requests.put(url=f"https://discord.com/api/guilds/{guild_id}/members/{user_id}", headers=headers, data=json_data)

            # json_response = response.json() # Easier to do, already parsed response

            print(response.status_code)
            print(response.text)
            return response.status_code            
        except Exception as error:
            print(f"Error occurred: {error}")
            return 500
```

Make sure you change where the token variable is placed, I put it inside the method for simplicity's sake.if you have any questions feel free to ask.